# vsts-npm-auth can't get authentication token on VSTS build

Tags: npm, azure-pipelines

I'm attempting to use [vsts-npm-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vsts-npm-auth) to get the authentication token for our VSTS package repository. On my development machine I can run the commands

`npm install -g vsts-npm-auth
vsts-npm-auth -config path-to-my\.npmrc`

and it succeeds in providing me with an authentication token. I'm now trying to recreate this as a build step on VSTS, so I create the powershell script `auth-vsts.ps1`

```
$npmrcFile = "$PSScriptRoot\path-to-my\.npmrc";
npm install -g vsts-npm-auth;
vsts-npm-auth -config $npmrcFile;
```

and add it as a powershell task. However, the task fails as follows

```
2017-05-30T09:37:41.1082686Z ##[section]Starting: auth-vsts
2017-05-30T09:37:41.1092712Z ==============================================================================
2017-05-30T09:37:41.1092712Z Task         : PowerShell
2017-05-30T09:37:41.1092712Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script
2017-05-30T09:37:41.1092712Z Version      : 1.2.3
2017-05-30T09:37:41.1092712Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-05-30T09:37:41.1092712Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613736)
2017-05-30T09:37:41.1092712Z ==============================================================================
2017-05-30T09:37:41.1112679Z ##[command]. 'd:\a\1\s\auth-vsts.ps1' 
2017-05-30T09:37:47.3792461Z C:\NPM\Modules\vsts-npm-auth -> C:\NPM\Modules\node_modules\vsts-npm-auth\bin\vsts-npm-auth.exe
2017-05-30T09:37:47.3792461Z C:\NPM\Modules
2017-05-30T09:37:47.3802239Z `-- vsts-npm-auth@0.25.0 
2017-05-30T09:37:47.3802239Z 
2017-05-30T09:37:47.3802239Z 
2017-05-30T09:37:47.3802239Z vsts-npm-auth v0.25.0.0 
2017-05-30T09:37:47.3802239Z -----------------------
2017-05-30T09:37:47.3802239Z Creating npmrcFile. Path: D:\a\1\s\.npmrc
2017-05-30T09:37:47.3802239Z Getting new credentials for source:https://our-domain/_packaging/SharedLib/npm/registry/, scope:vso.packaging_write vso.drop_write
2017-05-30T09:37:49.8729702Z Caught exception: The prompt option is invalid because the process is not interactive.
2017-05-30T09:37:49.8729702Z Parameter name: PromptType
2017-05-30T09:37:49.8729702Z Caught exception: The prompt option is invalid because the process is not interactive.
2017-05-30T09:37:49.8729702Z Parameter name: PromptType
2017-05-30T09:37:49.8729702Z Couldn't get an authentication token for //our-domain/_packaging/SharedLib/npm/registry/:_authToken.
2017-05-30T09:37:50.1769711Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
2017-05-30T09:37:50.1809715Z ##[section]Finishing: auth-vsts
```

The error gives no indication as to why it can't obtain the credentials. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Pipeline authentication
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows%2Cyaml#pipeline-authentication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error did indicate why it cannot obtain the credentials:

```
The prompt option is invalid because the process is not interactive.
```

This could be caused by the build agent does not run in interactive mode which make the credential dialog cannot be prompted. If you are using Hosted Build Agent, the build agent is run as service and there isn't any way to change to interactive mode.

However, the issue here is that if you want to use the feed in a build step, it does not make sense to prompt a credential dialog during the build process since the build step cannot enter the required credential automatically. Not sure if there is any specific requirement in your environment, but the general workflow should be uploading the .npmrc file generated in your local machine to the Source Control so that npm can use the auth token in the file to install/publish packages to VSTS Feed.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I had resorted to uploading/copying the .npmrc file with the auth token as part of the build pipeline to get it working (as per the VSTS/MSFT instructions for OsX and Linux)

Comment: how did you sort it out? what command did you use token the token

Answer (score 76):

Inside your project, you can open a terminal and run

```
 vsts-npm-auth -F -C .npmrc
```

This script refreshes the npm token. Here I set two parameters: **-F** forces the refresh (if not set, the token is refreshed only if it is already expired), while **-C** fileName defines the configuration file.

Comment: The force option made the trick for me, thank you !

Comment: Is there is any Linux equivalent command

Answer (score 13):

I faced this issue while trying to execute via Visual Studio Code`s **powershell** terminal

```
vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc
```

But running the same command via *simple console solved this issue* and I was redirected to authentication window.

Can suggest that due to internal limitations powershell disabled to open another windows.

Comment: I had to use the `-F` "force" flag to make it work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows%2Cclassic#unable-to-authenticate

Answer (score 5):

We ran this command:

1. npm i -g vsts-npm-auth
2. Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
3. vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc -F
4. npm i

Comment: Setting the execution policy resolved issue in my case.

Answer (score 2):

The vsts authentication system sometimes authenticates the use by popping up a browser window. If the terminal you're running the command from is not interactive (e.g., ssh terminal, vscode terminal) it won't be able to pop up that window, and the authentication will fail.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

npx vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc