# Set environment variable for VSTS build

Tags: azure-devops

I tried setting an environment variable (`NPM_TOKEN`) for VSTS on the `variables` tab / `Process variables` but it looks like the build process tool (NPM) doesn't recognize it.

I also tried to run a command line task `echo $NPM_TOKEN` which also fails:

```
Failed which: Not found echo $NPM_TOKEN: null
```

I tried using a `Hosted` Agent as well as a `Hosted Linux (Preview)` agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable can be recognized both for build and release. And you should use the variable as the format **`$(NPM_TOKEN)`.**

For **Command Line** task:

[image]

For **PowerShell** task:

[image]

---

Add .nmprc via web UI:

Open your project -> code -> make sure the git repo and branch is what your want to add file -> New file -> file name is `.npmrc` -> copy the token as content -> commit.

[image]

Comment: If I use it that way I get this error: npm ERR! 404 Not Found: <mynpmtoken>@latest because the npm command task now uses the variable as the package name to be installed. I need it to be set as an environment variable for my `npm install` build task

Comment: You should add the token to` .npmrc` file in `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` in order to execute npm commands. Besides you can also upload local `.npmrc` file with the token to source code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259383/vsts-npm-auth-cant-get-authentication-token-on-vsts-build.

Comment: Can I create the `.npmrc` file via VSTS UI? I don't want to check in this file into my git repository.

Comment: Yes, you can add `.npmrc` through web UI, and then copy the token into it.

Comment: Where can I do this (sorry, I'm pretty new to VSTS)?

Comment: The solution offered to add through the UI commits the token in the repo, which is a bad practice

Comment: @felixfbecker that’s the reason why I stopped using VSTS.